# vba array of types literal

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I defined the following type:

```
Public Type settings
    key As String
    german As String
    french As String
End Type
```

How does the correct code look like to define an array with ~100 literal entries?

Someting like:

```
Dim translations as Array() = {
   (key="send", german="Senden", french="Enregistrer"),
   (key="directory", german="Verzeichnis", french="Liste"),
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no nice syntax for that in VBA. If you really need to init an array of a user-defined type, you can use a couple of helper functions to do it like this:

```
Public Type settings
    key As String
    german As String
    french As String
End Type

Private Function NewTranslation(key As String, german As String, french As String) As settings
    NewTranslation.key = key
    NewTranslation.german = german
    NewTranslation.french = french
End Function

Private Sub AddTranslation(translations() As settings, value As settings)
    Dim u As Integer
    u = -1
    On Error Resume Next ' ubound raises an error if the array is not dimensioned yet
    u = UBound(translations)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ReDim Preserve translations(0 To u + 1) As settings
    translations(u + 1) = value
End Sub

Public Sub Main()
    Dim translations() As settings
    AddTranslation translations, NewTranslation("send", "Senden", "Enregister")
    AddTranslation translations, NewTranslation("directory", "Verzeichnis", "Liste")
    ' and so on
End Sub
```

A nicer way to do this particular problem would be a Collection (map) object using the language code and the original text as the key:

```
Private translations As New Collection

Public Sub Main()
    With translations
        .Add "Senden", "de:send"
        .Add "Enregister", "fr:send"
        .Add "Verzeichnis", "de:directory"
        .Add "Liste", "fr:directory"
    End With

    MsgBox GetTranslation("de", "send")
End Sub

Public Function GetTranslation(language As String, s As String)
    GetTranslation = s ' default to original text if no translation is available
    On Error Resume Next
    GetTranslation = translations(language + ":" + s)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question:
The way I handle translation text is to maintain it on an excel sheet (which is usually hidden inside the XLA addin), then read it (or just the column required for the current language) into a variant containing an array. 
 It is much easier to maintain and expand (add new languages or words) if you do it this way.

Comment: Ok, I see. That will be no problem for my Excel Add-In. But I have an almost identical Word Add-In. How could I include the excel sheet for the Word Add-In?

Comment: I am fairly ignorant about Word Addins, so don't know the best solution - maybe you would have to duplicate the information in a Word Table?